# If $f:{\Bbb R}^m \to {\Bbb R}^n$ is Lipschitz on all compact sets, under what conditions is $f$ a $C^1$ map?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, compactness, lipschitz-functions

> If $f:{\Bbb R}^m \to {\Bbb R}^n$ is Lipschitz on all compact sets, under what conditions is $f$ a $C^1$ map?

---

*Background*: I have proved the following result, and I am looking for a **converse**.

> **Proposition.** Let $f: {\Bbb R}^m \to {\Bbb R}^n$ be a $C^1$ mapping and let $K \subset {\Bbb R}^m$ be compact. Then the restriction $f|_K$ of $f$ to $K$ is Lipschitz continuous.

The proof of this result, and some special cases, can be found here: [Post 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140351/how-to-prove-f-is-lipschitz-continuous), [Post 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395944/proof-on-showing-function-f-in-c1-on-an-open-convex-set-u-subset-mathbb), [Post 3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851761/let-f-mathbbrn-rightarrow-mathbbrm-be-differentiable-and-k-subset), and [Post 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514958/f-in-c1-and-k-compact-prove-that-fk-to-%E2%84%9Dp-is-lipschitz-continuous).

---

In general, differentiability is a stronger condition than continuity, so there is no reason to expect the "Lipschitz on all compact sets" assumption above to imply differentiability. What other **additional assumptions** on $f$ would be required to ensure that it is a $C^1$ mapping?

[Rademacher's Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%2C%20Rademacher%27s%20theorem,set%20of%20Lebesgue%20measure%20zero.) is a related result; but I am clearly looking for something stronger.

**The goal** is to characterize $C^1$ maps in terms of Lipschitz continuity on compact sets, and other additional conditions if required.

Thank you, and I am excited to see where this goes!

Comment: Note $f(x) = |x|$ is Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$ (and therefore on all compact subsets) but not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: After thinking about this more carefully, I think I have identified a better example: [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function). It is everywhere differentiable with bounded derivative, and is therefore Lipschitz, but its derivative is very discontinuous.

Comment: Unfortunately, being $C^1$ is really stronger than being Lipschitz ...in the same way that if a function is bounded, then it tells you nothing about its discontinuities.

Comment: @LL3.14 is spot on. In fact it is easier to turn things around. Given any bounded and (locally) integrable function $f$ on $R$, the function $F(x):=\int_0^x f(t) dt$ is Lipschitz and its derivative... is it continuous?! Of interest to the OP will be the fact that after removing a set of measure as small as we want, a Lipschitz function coincides with a C^1 function! This is probably the best one can get.